# wordpress 3.6 media manager cropping timestamp

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, media-settings

I am using wordpress 3.6 with its default media manager,

I uploaded an image, and then every time i crop it, it create 3/4 new images in upload directory with different name (adding timestamp in file name), But I can't see those newely created(cropped) images in my media library. I can see them on upload folder using ftp.

Why it is doing is? is there solution within wordpress without any code hack?

I am expecting its behaviour after cropping.

either

it should overwrite exiting files(all sizes)

or

if it creates new files with timestamp, it should show those files in media library so i can choose them.

UPDATE:
Now If you look at the screenshot below, 
You see how cropping working. 
There are three types of colour coding,

1. Original Images (when Image uploaded first time, it generated 4 types of image sizes automatically)
2. First time crop (when I cropped the image first time using media manager, it created 4 sizes of images again)
3. second time crop ( when I cropped the same image second time it created another set of 3 images)
4. third time crop ( when I cropped the same image third time it created another set of 3 images)

And it will keep going on every time i crop image 3 new images will be added. which is totally redundancy. While in Media image library I will only see one image. I can't delete my previous cropped image, neither do it replace previous cropped sets.

When I Set Feature Image of Post after all these cropping, somehow it still choose image A-604x270.jpg from Original Image to display it in Feature Image. I can I get most recent cropped image to display As Feature Image.

Previously cropped image, as i can access them from admin area, means I can delete time. How can I delete perviously cropped image, otherwise it will be waste of space.

Honestly It is very unusual way of cropping system in wordpress.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those new files are your original file resized. When you insert an image and pick 'medium' 'thumbnail' or 'large', they aren't generated on the fly or pulled out of thin air. They're created when you upload the image to save size.

The reason you can't see these in the media section is because the media section does not display files you've uploaded, it displays attachment posts, which represent an image and all its sizes.

So you don't need to do anything to show them, they're already shown, and you can already choose them, just pick the relevant size

E.g. These are all different sizes of a single image attachment listed on my site:

- http://www.tomjn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/9.jpg
- http://www.tomjn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/9-150x150.jpg
- http://www.tomjn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/9-300x201.jpg

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question Please see if you can help me out. I still can't choose "Feature Image" from cropped one.

Comment: You mean you want to undo the cropping? As I said and shall say again, you do not pick files, you pick attachment posts. The file does not show in the listing because it does not list files, it lists posts.